# 予定や経学が実際と違った場合を話してください

Tags: grammar

> 予定や経学が実際と違った場合を話してください。

I intentionally left my translation in this rather desolate state because it shows my 2 problems very well. My translation:

> Please talk about a case where plans and plans practical and changed.

1. I don't really know how to convey a semantical difference between 予定 and 実際.
2. 実際 is a noun here, but 違った is a verb. Since 違った is past tense, I could imagine coaxing some noun-ish semantics into it since it kind of describes a state (in the end, past suggests that something has happened/is finished already). Nevertheless, even if both were nouns I wouldn't know how to give it a meaningful interpretation, because
   (NOUN (subject) + が + complex noun-ish phrase + 場合) = object of the full sentence

Comment: Is it okay for 経学? not 計画 from the plans in your sentence？

Comment: I've never before asked for a mere translation and I didn't this time as well. 

I indeed have an idea what the sentence wants to tell me. I shall talk about cases where reality and plans didn't match, or in other words, where I couldn't realize the plans I had. 

I didn't write this because I didn't think it would be necessary to understand my problems with the grammar of the sentence, not its content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How does this sentence work?

- AがBと違った場合 = "a case when/if A was different from B"

  B is "reality", so "a case when/if A was different from reality"

  A consists of A<sup>1</sup> and A<sup>2</sup> connected by "or" (A<sup>1</sup>やA<sup>2</sup>); as of this moment A<sup>2</sup> contains a typo, but it doesn't influence how this sentence works
- を話してください = "tell me about", "give me an example"

Answer (score 0):

I assume that 経学 in your sentence is 計画.

I'd translate.

**Could you tell me if you are going to do and what you are planning were to different from what will have happened?**

違った is used in the hypothetical condition.